# Calling & Displaying Attachments from Sub-Pages - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, if-statement, attachment

I'm new to WordPress (duh) and trying something I'm very close to getting.

I have several Sub-Pages, each of which has attachments - images. I simply want to display these images. The client will regularly be adding more subpages so the code has to know to only display the images of its self, so to speak. An issue I'm running into is **each** subpage is displaying **all** the attachments of all **subpages**.

In my `Functions.php` I have this code to determine if the page is infact a subpage:

```
//find out if it is a suppage to use in page.php as function 'is_subpage'
function is_subpage() {
    global $post;                              // load details about this page

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {   // test to see if the page has a parent
        return $post->post_parent;             // return the ID of the parent post

    } else {                                   // there is no parent so ...
        return false;                          // ... the answer to the question is false
    }
}
```

In my `page.php` I have an If statement, for all my usual pages. It culminates in this:

```
    elseif ( is_subpage() ) {
      get_template_part( 'exhibition-template' );
      get_template_part( 'normalfooter' );
    }
```

In `exhibition-template.php`, where I want my images to appear I have this:

```
<?php

if ( is_subpage( $post->ID ) ) { //I think I screwed up here, innermost brackets


$args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID, //or is my issue here...?
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => -1,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'large', false, false);
        }
    }
}    
?>
```

However, what happens is each and every subpage simply displays all the images across all subpages, and frankly, I'm just too DUMB to know how to progress, or what to play with, where to start. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Let me introduce you to your new friend, var_dump() http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php . First I'd include something to get var_dumped out in the conditional to see which condition is being met within your function. Then I'd make sure it knows what $post->ID is in your exhibition-template, i.e. var_dump($post->ID).

Comment: Thank you - Ive never understood however WHERE it dumps the info, where would the debug / errors / outputs actually appear?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a few issues.

When testing to see if a page is a subpage you should test to see if `$post->post_parent` is greater than 0. So like this:

```
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
    return $post->post_parent;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You do not need to pass any arguments into `if ( is_subpage( $post->ID ) )..`. You could also just use WordPress' `get_attached_media()` function to get these attachements as well. This is how your `exhibition-template.php` could look:

```
if ( is_subpage() ) {

    $attachments = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);

    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'large', false, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for this, love trimming the fat. However now -all- my subpages are -only- displaying the attachment images that are from -the most recent- subpage, - sorry to bug I really appreciate it but, any thoughts?

Comment: This should return the attachments from the page that is currently being viewed. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: No, all that happens is on **every** subpage, it is returning the attachments from the **most current** subpage, and that page only. The URLs are correct, as are other Custom Fields associated with each subpage displaying correctly so I know I'm not being redirected to the most recent subpage each time. Each subpage is just only grabbing and displaying the attached images from the most recent page, exclusively.

Comment: There may be an issue with the `$post->ID`. This will need to be the ID of the page that has the attachments that need to be shown. You could echo this ID out to make sure that it matches up with the proper page.

Comment: i could be wrong but what my problem seems to boil down to is "How do I find the **ID** of the **CURRENT** Sub-page". That is, w/o plugging in its static ID, I need the template to work dynamically for forthcoming subpages. Everything I have found so far lists all subpages of a parent, but i cant find a way to isolate the current/active subpage and retrieve it's ID. If that could be put into a variable and replaced there, then it would work perfectly. Whenever I echo the ID i get the ID of the most recent subpage, the one who's images are displaying, even though I'm not on that subpage.

Comment: Assuming that this is used in the loop, you can use `get_the_ID()` to get the current page id.

Comment: lol i can feel the interest in this topic waning and I dont blame you. I've used get_the_ID() in the loop, and it always returns the ID '136' which is still, the ID of the most current Subpage. zero idea.

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out. damn. I had to open and close The Loop within my template, I was casting a wider net and opening the loop in my header and closing it in my footer. after I put it all in the template, which works for this site, all is well. THANK YOU